# Defence against civil claim from a non-contractual party

Tags: united-states, contract-law, civil-law, damages

There are three parties `A`, `B`, and `C`.

`A` provides **X** service on a contractual basis to `B`. `B` on the other hand provides **Y** service (which is related to **X**, think about door service and parking service) to `C` on a contractual basis, but has a waiver stating:

> Party `C` indemnifies party `B` harmless from any damages that party
> `A` may cause.

There was a damage incurred by party `C`. `C` is holding `B` harmless, as there is no contractual agreement between `A` and `C`. `B` requires `C` to hold `B` harmless against any negligence from `A`. No info on jurisdiction, please assume US.

Can party `C` still bring a claim against `B`? Or should they sue party `A` directly? There is no contractual agreement between `A` and `C`.

Comment: There is not enough information here to give a useful answer. What has been done, and by who, to give rise a suit? What kind of suit? what jurisdiction? If C has no contractual agreement with A, why is C holding A harmless? Or does B require C to hold all of B's contractors harmless? Some actions cannot be covered by a waiver in advance, but many can.

Comment: There was a damage incurred by the party `C`. `C` is holding `B` harmless, as there is no contractual agreement between `A` and `C`. `B` requires `C` to hold `B` harmless against any negligence from `A`. No info on jurisdiction, please assume US.

Comment: Who caused the harm? Your question just says that it was incurred by party `C`.

Comment: @RyanM "*Who caused the harm?*" Party *A*. The OP refers to "*damages that party A may cause*" and then again to "*negligence from A*".

Comment: @RyanM, as Iñaki Viggers mentioned. the harm was caused by party A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can party C still bring a claim against B? Or should they sue party A directly?

*C* ought to sue *A*. I'm assuming *C* agreed to the waiver (or else *B* would have declined to enter the contract with *C*).

The waiver is a form of *remedies* clause in the contract between *B* and *C*. These two parties agree on which conditions *C* may sue *B*.

Even if alleging a[n indirect] contract between *C* and *A* fails, your description reflects that *C* is a *beneficiary* of the contract between *A* and *B*. This creates a duty *A* owes to *C*. In other words, *C* may --and agreed to-- assert his rights against *A*. See [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at §309(1).

Comment: thanks, this makes sense! Yes, `C` did agree to the waiver put forth by `B`. There is no contract between `A` and `C` (parking users may keep changing but `B` still got to maintain the door with the help/service of `A`) whatsoever.

Comment: The nature of the suit would depend upon the nature of the wrong by A. Often a suit by C against A would be a tort lawsuit rather than a third-party beneficiary of contract suit. But the facts in the question aren't specific enough to know.

Comment: @ohwilleke "*Often a suit by C against A would be a tort lawsuit rather than a third-party beneficiary of contract suit*". The OP clearly refers to harm that *A* causes as per *A*'s role in the contract between *B* and *C*. Hence, that sounds in contract dispute, not tort. Black's Law Dict. defines *tort* as "*[a] wrong independent of contract*". See also [*Tingler v. Graystone Homes, Inc*, 834 S.E.2d 244, 254-256 (2019)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/invaco20191104i04), [*Anderson v. Ford Ranch, LLC*, (NV CoA, Nov., 2020)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/innvco20201127050), and many others.

Comment: @IñakiViggers But when parties are not in direct privity with each other, they often resort to tort instead. For example, even though defective construction of a building would often be a breach of contract, suits for defective construction of a building are usually brought as tort negligence suits when there is not direct privity of contract. The history of product liability law reflects the same trend.

Comment: @ohwilleke Privity of contract is irrelevant in the OP's scenario because *A* knows, or should know, that the intended first purchaser --or first intended "end user"-- of his services is *C*, not *B*. [*Utz v. Moss*, 503 P.2d 365, 367 (1972)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1972868503p2d3651851) applied that rationale toward holding that "*the implied warranty [...] extends to that first purchaser*".